# Когда я пришёл, всё было хророшо, и(,) что он делал до этого, я не знаю

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Когда я пришёл, всё было хророшо, и(,) что он делал до этого, я не знаю.

> Сейчас я закончил, но(,) когда послезавтра я кончу, я не знаю-таки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение методом блоков:

***Когда я пришёл**, всё было хорошо, и **что** он делал до этого, **я не знаю.***

***Сейчас я закончил**, но когда послезавтра закончу, **я не знаю-таки.***

Вторая часть предложений имеет сходную структуру: сочинительный союз ***И/НО*** относится к СПП с придаточным **изъяснительным** в препозиции.

Comment: Ссылка на правило Лопатина  § 132.  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136

Answer (score 1):

Я всë же считаю, что нужна:

*Когда я пришёл, всё было хорошо, и [то], что он делал до этого, я не знаю*;

*Сейчас я закончил, но [то], когда послезавтра я кончу, я не знаю-таки*.

Сочинительные союзы относятся ко второй главной части.

Ср.:

*Когда я пришёл, всё было хорошо, и я не знаю [то], что он делал до этого*;

*Сейчас я закончил, но я не знаю-таки [то], когда послезавтра я кончу*.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку на правило, по которому выбрано ваше решение.  Или образец такого решения в литературных текстах. Паузы после союза И нет, какой смысл в лишней запятой? Почему вы не пользуетесь официальным правилом Лопатина в предложении, где 3 или 4 предикативные основы? Рассмотрим отдельное предложение: И что он делал до этого, я не знаю.  В таком предложении тоже нужна запятая?

Comment: Вы не понимаете таких простых вещей, что предложение с несколькими основами  (по смыслу и интонации) делится на две части, поэтому важно обозначить смысловые отношения между этими частями, а не дробить предложение запятыми на отдельные речевые отрезки.

Comment: @Sharon Правильный ваш вариант или нет (спорить тут не буду), но постановка ни в коем случае не ошибка. Нужно смотреть, куда МОЖЕТ относиться союз и по этому отделять от него придаточное или нет.

Comment: И галочку я сейчас не прошу ни от кого.

Comment: А кто спорит?  И дело не в галочках, хотя вы активно ищете ошибки именно в моих ответах. Я прошу дать ссылку на правило. Я решаю по Лопатину, это известное правило. Будьте добры, если можно.

Comment: 1. Я без ссылки работал. Проводил свой анализ. 2.Я в поиск кое-что ввел, мне попался этот вопрос. 3. Даже если ваш вприант верен, мой нельзя считать ошибкой, если вдуматься в мой анализ.

Comment: Извините, но любой анализ делается на основе правила и в соответствии с правилами.  А ваше решение противоречит правилу Лопатина.  Лишняя запятая препятствует восприятию сложного предложения как цельной конструкции, состоящей из двух основных частей. А если автор хотел бы обозначить сочинительную связь главных частей по образцу "всё было хорошо, и я не знаю", он бы выбрал структуру СПП без инверсии придаточного.

Comment: Из грамматики: Грамматическим значением сложного предложения являются смысловые отношения между его частями, в то время как для простого предложения это предикативная основа.  В русском синтаксисе еще много вещей, которые вам неизвестны, и зря вы думаете, что все освоили, так что и спрашивать вам уже не о чем.  И поисками своими в Сети вы ничего не докажете. Ищите грамматические источники и ссылайтесь на них, если правило не можете подобрать.

Comment: Я все обосновал. Больше мне нечего добавить. У меня пропадает стремление в этом сайте к чему-либо. Так что еще что-то приводить вам, чтобы доказать свое мнение, мне нет смысла, т. к. к галочке я не стремлюсь совсем.

Comment: На этом сайте надо давать качественные ответы. Это все, что надо на этом сайте. Ваш ответ верен на 60 %, не более того.  Это если пользоваться вашей шкалой верности) Давайте, Максим, займемся делом. Задавайте интересные вопросы и давайте хорошие ответы по НОВЫМ темам. И перестанем заниматься разборками, это не повышает репутацию сайта. Ответьте лучше  на мой вопрос https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476970/Можно-ли-так-изменить-предложение-чтобы-обособленный-оборот-стал-необособленным, вы же интересовались этой темой.